# Why Lat and Long values through attribute table in ArcMap are not accurate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, geometry

I calculated the lat, long in metres through the attribute table, and the values are very course (i.e., varying in +/-50m only).

But, when I move the mouse cursor over the points, the lat long values are much finer (mm)

Example: It's varying in around 22 metres with x coordinate when I moved from 1 point to its immediate neighbor point, but it's not reflected in the attribute table.

[image: of First point]

Refer the screenshots in the attachments.

[image: of Second point]

[image: Lat, long values are not varying, even though the points are 25metres apart]

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Note: These aren't latitude and longitude values which would be in degrees. These are in a projected coordinate reference system using meters.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your shapefile coordinate system and your map coordinate system if they are the same, also the units.  otherwise, you will get these differences. so you need to make them compatible in reference system and recalculate the x-coord of your points in the shapefile (as a float with 3 decimal points and check again

Have a look to the attached sample when the coordinate systems are different
[image]